# What is the pure http syntax to make GET request with JSON body

Tags: json, httprequest, get-request

Hey can some one show me an example of **pure http syntax** to make GET request with **JSON body**?
Like:

```
https://example.com/getUser?user[id]=123&user[name]=username
```

is to send a php array.
But what if I want to send this as a JSON array?

(I know it is very simple with cURL or other ways, but I am trying to learn the **basics**.)

Comment: Add the JSON you want to post in the question details, also you want a pure HTTP way of sending it, or the javascript way (XMLHttpRequest) ?

Comment: I want pure HTTP way.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest HTTP request is:

```
GET /getUser?user[id]=123&user[name]=username HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com
```

If you want to send data in the body, you need a method that allows sending a body, like POST

```
POST /getUser HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com

{ id: 123, name: 'username' }
```

Comment: ya but am looking for json body.

Comment: You cannot send JSON data through a GET request; if you want to send a body, you need a POST request.